# how to subtract from counter - new to javascript

Tags: javascript

when click on button "magic" i need it to triger  kashef() func.
it has to calculate two variables and decrease the result from the counter showed in 1000</p. for example if counter shows 1000 and i press "magic" btn, the counter decrese to 800 (if resut = 200) and move forward to count from 800
couldnt fined a way to dothat- i new to javascrip
thanks!!!

```js
let start // set on the first step to the timestamp provided
const el = document.getElementById('count') // get the element
const final = parseInt(el.textContent, 5) // parse out the final number
const duration = 100001 // duration in ms

const time;
const progress;

const step = ts => {
  if (!start) {
    start = ts
  }
  // get the time passed as a fraction of total duration
  let progress = (ts - start) / duration
  el.textContent = Math.floor(progress * final) * 100 // set the text
  time = el.textContent
  if (progress < 1) {
    // if we're not 100% complete, request another animation frame

  }
  requestAnimationFrame(step)

  const btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
  const btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
  const btn3 = document.getElementById('btn3');

  const kashefCost;
  const sovevCost;
  const shatekCost;

  // when buttons open
  const OpentButtons = 200

  if (time <= OpentButtons) {
    btn1.disabled = true;
    btn2.disabled = true;
    btn3.disabled = true;

  } else {
    btn1.disabled = false;
    btn2.disabled = false;
    btn3.disabled = false;
  }
}

function kashef() {
  kashefCost = 200
  const result;
  result = time - kashefCost
  el.value = result

}

requestAnimationFrame(step)
```

```html
<html>

<header>

  <p id="count">1000</p </header>

  <form>
    <input type="button" onclick="kashef()" id="btn3" value="(200$)magic">
    <input type="button" onclick="sovev()" id="btn2" value="  
    (100$) roll" />
    <input type="button" onclick="shatek()" id="btn1" value="(50$) mute" />
  </form>

  <body>

    <p id="text">alert:</p>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why is the `<form>` before `<body>`?

Comment: `time` and `progress` can't be `const`, since you update them.

Comment: the code works but i will adjast to conformto your comments .  how can i  subtract my timer?

Comment: `time -= 200;` will subtract 200 from `time`

Comment: i need to subtract  200 from the running counter.

Comment: Which variable is the running counter?

Comment: thanks Barmar. sorry, not  sure. i elaborated existing code. tried to figure it my self but stacked

Comment: I tried decrementing the `count` element. The problem is that the `step()` function resets it using the `progress` variable. I think you need to redesign this if you want to be able to reset the counter. Maybe you should add to `start`.

Comment: Why do you have `5` in this: `parseInt(el.textContent, 5)`? Why would you parse it in base 5?

Comment: thanks barmar 5 base - i just played with it and got the right pase for me that the counter running. not realy deep thoughts :)

Comment: Normally you would use base 10. Which is the default.

Comment: thanks barmar. i updated it to 10 based in my code :)